# A proof of Jacobsthal identities

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I have heard of the following result: if $p=a^2+b^2\equiv1\pmod4$, and if $a$ is odd, while $b$ is even, then

> $\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}(\frac{x^3-nx}{p})=\pm 2a\ $ for $n$ a residue of $p$;
>   $\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}(\frac{x^3-nx}{p})=\pm 2b\ $ for $n$ a non-residue of $p$;
>   and the sum is $0\ $ for $p\equiv-1\pmod4$.

However I could not find a proof of this result, other than [one document](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7R7MAVT--Fkdnk4QnR2OXFQRmM/edit), in which one finds a proof using L-functions of elliptic curves. but some of the lemmas are not associated with a proof, and are not so obvious. Since the author says that there are elementary ways of proving it, one then asks how can one prove this.
P.S. the references in the document are beyond my reach. So any reference is also welcomed.

Comment: By 'residue' do you mean 'quadratic residue'?

Comment: The last piece goes like this: if $p\equiv-1\pmod4$, then $-1$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$, so $\left({x^3-nx\over p}\right)=-\left({(p-x)^3-n(p-x)\over p}\right)$, and each term in the lower half of the range of $x$ cancels the term with $p-x$ in the upper half of the range. The first two parts, I suspect they are done in the outstanding text by Ireland and Rosen.

Comment: @Berci: Yes I mean quadratic residues, as is seen in the document given.

Comment: @GerryMyerson[Do you mean this book?](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/A_Classical_Introduction_to_Modern_Numbe.html?id=jhAXHuP2y04C&redir_esc=y)Thanks in any case for the excellent explanation.

Comment: Yes, that's the book.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have inspected the book, but yet found nothing related now. Maybe I missed something? Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it would be in there, but I don't see it, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the book by Ireland and Rosen shows a lot on Jacobi sums, the name
“Jacobstahl” does not even appear in the index. I found out the original
article by Jacobstahl however, and I reproduce the revelant part here. Let us
put for $m$ between $1$ and $p-1$,

$$
\phi(m)=\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\bigg(\frac{x^3-mx}{p}\bigg) \tag{1}
$$

The basic idea is to compute the sum $S=\sum_{m=1}^{p-1} \phi(m)^2$ in two different
ways. Let $y$ be an integer in $[1,p-1]$; for any $x\in [1,p-1]$ there is a unique
$x'\in [1,p-1]$ such that $x' \equiv yx \ ({\sf mod} \ p)$. Then we can rewrite
$\phi(m)$ :

$$
\phi(m)=\sum_{x'=1}^{p-1}\bigg(\frac{(\frac{x’}{y})^3-m\frac{x'}{y}}{p}\bigg)
=\sum_{x'=1}^{p-1}\bigg(\frac{y}{p}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{(x')^3-my^2x’}{p}\bigg)
$$

We have thus shown

$$
\phi(m)=\bigg(\frac{y}{p}\bigg) \phi(m{y^2}) \ (\text{for any} \ m,y\in [1,p-1])\tag{2}
$$

We deduce that $\phi^2$ is constant on the set of residues and constant on the set of nonresidues, so that

$$
S=\frac{p-1}{2} (\phi(r)^2+\phi(s)^2) \tag{3}
$$
where $r$ is any residue, and $s$ is any nonresidue.

Now direct computation yields

$$
S=\sum_{m,x,y} \bigg(\frac{x^3-mx}{p}\bigg) \bigg(\frac{y^3-my}{p}\bigg)
=\sum_{x,y} \bigg(\frac{xy}{p}\bigg) \sum_{m} \bigg(\frac{(m-x^2)(m-y^2)}{p}\bigg) \tag{4}
$$

At this point, we need the following

**Lemma.**  For any integers $b,c$, we have
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{p} \bigg(\frac{m^2+bm+c}{p}\bigg)=p-1-p \bigg(\frac{b^2-4c}{p}\bigg)^2
$$

**Proof of lemma** . Using a change of indices, it is clear that the
sum $\sum_{m=1}^{p} \bigg(\frac{m^2+bm+c}{p}\bigg)$ only depends on the discriminant 
$b^2-4c$, we can thus write it as $\psi(b^2-4c)$ where $\psi$ is a function. Since
$\bigg(\frac{m^2-d}{p}\bigg)$ is the same thing as $(m^2-d)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ modulo
$p$, we see that

$$
\psi(d)=\sum_{m=1}^{p} (m^2-d)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv (-1) \ ({\sf mod}\ p)
$$
as one can check by expanding each summand as a Newton binomial.
Since $\psi(d)$ is also a sum of $p$ integers between $-1$ and $1$, it can only equal $-1$ or $p-1$. Finally, we have that

$$
\sum_{d=0}^{p-1} \psi(d)= \sum_{m=1}^{p-1}\sum_{d=0}^{p-1}\bigg(\frac{m^2-d}{p}\bigg)=0
$$

so the only possibility is that $\psi$ is $p-1$ at some point and $-1$ at all
the other points. We conclude the proof of this lemma by remarking that trivially $\psi(0)=p-1$.

Returning to our computation of $S$ in (4), we apply the lemma and deduce

$$
S=\sum_{x,y} \bigg(\frac{xy}{p}\bigg) (p-1-p \bigg(\frac{(x^2-y^2)^2}{p}\bigg)^2)=
$$

We can split the above sum in three, consider the sums $S_1,S_2,S_3$ by restricting
the range of $(x,y)$ with the conditions $y=x, y=(-x) {\sf mod}\ p$, and $x^2-y^2 \neq 
0\ {\sf mod}\ p$ respectively.

Then $S_1=(p-1)^2$, $S_2=\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)(p-1)^2$, and $S_3=(1+\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)) (p-1)$, and hence $S=(1+\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)) p(p-1)$.

When $p \equiv 1 \ ({\sf mod}\ 4)$, we have $S=2p(p-1)$ and combining this with (3) we deduce

$$
p=(\frac{\phi(r)}{2})^2+(\frac{\phi(s)}{2})^2,
$$

as wished.

**EDIT**  : Here are some more details on some points I explained rather
quickly above.

**The Newton binomial stuff :**    If we define $q=\frac{p-1}{2}$ and

$$
T=\sum_{m=1}^{p} (m^2-d)^{\frac{p-1}{2}},
$$

then we have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
T &=& \sum_{m=1}^{p} \sum_{j=0}^{q}\binom{q}{j}(m^2)^jd^{q-j})  \\
&=& \sum_{m=1}^{p} \Bigg(d^q+\sum_{j=1}^{q}\binom{q}{j}(m^2)^jd^{q-j})\Bigg)  \\
&=& \sum_{m=1}^{p} \Bigg(\sum_{j=1}^{q}\binom{q}{j}(m^2)^jd^{q-j}\Bigg) \ ({\sf mod} \ p)  \\
&=& \sum_{m=1}^{p} \sum_{j=1}^{q}\binom{q}{j}d^{q-j}(m^{2j}) \\
&=&  \sum_{j=1}^{q} \binom{q}{j}d^{q-j} T_{2j} \tag{*},
\end{array}
$$
where $T_k=\sum_{m=1}^{p} m^{k}$. Since $x \mapsto x+1$ is a permutation of $\frac{\mathbb Z}{p{\mathbb Z}}$, we have $\sum_{m=1}^{p}(m+1)^{k+1}-m^k=0$. Expanding $(m+1)^{k+1}$ as a Newton binomial, we deduce

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{k+1}{j} T_j=0 
$$

and when $k+1$ is not divisible by $p$ we can rewrite this as

$$
T_k=-\frac{1}{k+1} \big( \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j} T_j \big)
$$

which allows to compute the $T_k$ by induction. Starting from $T_0=(-1)$, we see that
$T_k=0$ for $0<k<p-1$. For $k=p-1$ we have $T_{p-1}=(-1)$ (in this case all the summands in $T_k$ are $1$ except the one for $m=p$).

We deduce that only the term for  $j=q$ is nonzero in the last line of (*), so $T=(-1)$.

**Computation of $S_3$ :**

We have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
S_3 &=& \sum_{y\neq x,y \neq (p-x) } \bigg(\frac{xy}{p}\bigg)(p-1-p)\\
&=&  -\sum_{y\neq x,y \neq (p-x) } \bigg(\frac{xy}{p}\bigg)  \\
&=&  -\sum_{x,y} \bigg(\frac{xy}{p}\bigg)+\sum_{y=x} \bigg(\frac{xy}{p}\bigg)+\sum_{y=p-x} \bigg(\frac{xy}{p}\bigg) \\
&=&  -\big(\sum_{x} \bigg(\frac{x}{p}\bigg) \big) \big(\sum_{y} \bigg(\frac{y}{p}\bigg) \big)+\sum_{x} \bigg(\frac{x^2}{p}\bigg)+\sum_{x} \bigg(\frac{-x^2}{p}\bigg) \\
&=&  -0 \times 0 +\sum_{x} 1+\sum_{x} \bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg) \\
&=& (p-1)(1+\bigg(\frac{-1}{p}\bigg)). 
\end{array}
$$

**EDIT 2 : Parity issue**  Suppose $p \equiv 1 \ ({\sf mod}\ 4)$, $p=4t+1$ with $t\in {\mathbb Z}$. To show that $a=\frac{\phi(r)}{2}$ and
$b=\frac{\phi(s)}{2}$, it will suffice to show that $\frac{\phi(r)}{2}$ is odd
for any residue $r$. Let us show it for $r=1$.

We have 
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\phi(1) &=& \sum_{x=1}^{p-1} \bigg( \frac{x^3-x}{p}\bigg) \\
&=& \sum_{x=1}^{p-1} \bigg( \frac{x(x-1)(x+1)}{p}\bigg) \\
&=& \sum_{x=2}^{p-2} \bigg( \frac{x(x-1)(x+1)}{p}\bigg) \\
&=& \sum_{j=1}^{p-3} \bigg( \frac{j(j+1)(j+2)}{p}\bigg)
\end{array}
$$

Let us put $\eta(j)=j(j+1)(j+2)$. Note that $\eta(-j)=-\eta(j-2)$, and hence

$$
\bigg( \frac{\eta(-j)}{p}\bigg)=\bigg( \frac{-1}{p}\bigg)\bigg( \frac{\eta(j-2)}{p}\bigg)=
\bigg( \frac{\eta(j-2)}{p}\bigg)
$$

So
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\phi(1) &=&  \sum_{j=1}^{2t-1} \bigg( \frac{\eta(j)}{p}\bigg)+
\sum_{j=2t}^{4t-2} \bigg( \frac{\eta(j)}{p}\bigg) \\
&=& \sum_{j=1}^{2t-1} \bigg( \frac{\eta(j)}{p}\bigg)+
\sum_{k=3}^{2t+1} \bigg( \frac{\eta(p-k)}{p}\bigg) \\
&=& \sum_{j=1}^{2t-1} \bigg( \frac{\eta(j)}{p}\bigg)+
\sum_{k=3}^{2t+1} \bigg( \frac{\eta(k-2)}{p}\bigg) \\
&=& 2\sum_{j=1}^{2t-1} \bigg( \frac{\eta(j)}{p}\bigg)
\end{array}
$$

So $\frac{\phi(1)}{2}$ is a sum of an odd number of signs, and is therefore odd.

Comment: Thanks for this miraculous answer, clarifying all my doubts.